# why my android app works fine in emulator but display is totally terrible in real device/

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i made an android app and it looks good in different screen sizes in emulator but when i run it in a real device, it runs but the display is totally terrible! i am using linear layout in my XML and my code for it is below. i have a table with some rows which contains data. it fits good with emulator but with real device the apps runs but display is totally bad. do not get it why runs good in emulator and bad in real device although its same resolution!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBMj3.jpg    on emulator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3PXE.jpg    running on emulator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BGkG.jpg    running on real device

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3xm2.jpg      linearlayout width and height is match parent

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical">


            <TableLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:weightSum="10">



                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="5"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" IP "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:weightSum="10"
                        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:weightSum="10"
                        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:weightSum="10"
                        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"

                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
                </TableRow>


                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=" "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>



 </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do share screenshots of both.

Comment: Set linearlayout width nd height to match parent

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar i have added one more screenshot for linearlayout width nd height to match parent  ... did not work

Comment: The issue here is if u see clearly your emulator is a wide screen due to which it's showing properly whereas your real device is more narrow. Set the column to 2 in this case and the width of each column to 0 and height 1

Comment: thanks man it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added weightsum for you TableRow. You need to make changes as below -

Replace weightsum for first TableRow to 3

```
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border">
```

Also remove below line from Child TextViews

```
android:weightSum="10"
```

Add below lines to Child TextViews

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

I hope it will work for you.